# Matlab, matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to create a matrix where I have points in a 0-1 range simulating a xor gate like in the picture bu points should exist in upper left and bottom right corners too.

[image]

I am using this code:

```
    pats = [0.4*rand(n/4,2);
            0.4*rand(n/4,2)+0.6;
            0.4*rand(n/4,2)+[0 0.5];
            0.4*rand(n/4,2)-[0 0.5]+0.6];
```

And I get the following error:

```
Warning: Size vector should be a row
vector with integer elements. 
> In main at 24 
Warning: Size vector should be a row
vector with integer elements. 
> In main at 24 
Warning: Size vector should be a row
vector with integer elements. 
> In main at 24 
Warning: Size vector should be a row
vector with integer elements. 
> In main at 24 
Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in main (line 24)
        pats = [0.4*rand(n/4,2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element wise addition doesn't work for your `randn(n/4,2) + [0 0.5]` because you are trying to add a `n/4` by 2 matrix to a 1 by 2 matrix. You need to use `bsxfun`:

```
pats = [0.4*rand(n/4,2);
    0.4*rand(n/4,2)+0.6;
    bsxfun(@plus,0.4*rand(n/4,2),[0 0.5]);
    bsxfun(@minus,0.4*rand(n/4,2),[0 0.5]) + 0.6];
```

The function `bsxfun(@plus, A, b)` will add the i-th element of `b` to the i-th column of matrix `A`.